# sql select to display posts in pairs, with classic asp

Tags: sql, select, asp-classic

I need to display post from the db in pairs, and Im not sure whats the best way of doing it.
The page is done with classic asp.

I want to get this structure :

```
<ul>
<li>

<img src="image_1.jpg" />
<img src="image_2.jpg" />

</li>
<li>

<img src="image_3.jpg" />
<img src="image_4.jpg" />

</li>
</ul>
```

So how do I do it with asp, if I start with the below?

```
    <ul>

<% do until rs.eof%>
    <li>

    <img src="<%=rs("image")%>" />


    </li>
<% rs.movenext
   loop %>
```

Any input appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with this code:

```
<ul>
<% dim irecordcount
irecordcount=1
%>

<li>

<% do until rs.eof %>

<img src="<%=rs("big_image")%>" />
<!--Im only displaying 30 images and here I write the </li><li> if it an even row, and also I dont write the last </li><li>-->
<%if irecordcount mod 2=0 and irecordcount <>30 then%>
</li>
<li>
<% end if
irecordcount=irecordcount+1
rs.movenext
loop%>
 </li>          
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a variation on the how do I get alternating table row colours in Classic ASP question. Basically it involves running a count as you loop through your recordset and checking if the current value is odd or even.  There are plenty of examples if you google - here's one

http://www.aspwebpro.com/aspscripts/database/alternaterowcolor.asp

In this example, rather than specifying a table row you could do something like

```
<ul>
<li>    
<% iRecordCount = 0 
do until rs.eof
iRecordCount = iRecordCount+1 %>
<img src="<%=rs("image")%>" />
<% IF iRecordCount Mod 2 = 0 THEN %>
</li>
<li>
<% END IF %>
<% rs.movenext
loop 
IF iRecordCount Mod 2 = 0 THEN %>
</ul>
<% else %>
</li>
</ul>
<% end if %>
```

It might be worth asking CSS people if they have any ideas. I'm sure I've seen what you're looking for done as a basic unordered list

Comment: Thanks John. But I dont want to get even or odd record sets, I want to  display them 2 and 2, the first 2 inside a li, the next 2 inside the next li and so on, like in my post above.

Comment: Yes, what I suggested will do that.  If irecordcount is even then the li tag is closed and a new one opened, if it's odd then only the image tag appears.  I've edited my answer to show how it would fit in your recordset, and a bit of code at the end to close the li tag if recordcount finished on an odd number

Comment: Hi John, and thanks a lot. You are right, I was a bit tired I guess.
I solved it - see my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a variable, increment and then reset it:

```
Dim i = 1

Do until rs.EOF
  If i = 1 Then
    Response.Write "<li>"
  End If

  Response.Write "<img src=""" & rs("image") & """ />"

  If i>=2 Then
    Response.Write "</li>"
    i = 0
  End If

  i = i + 1
  rs.movenext
Loop
```